# Postgres Gin index definition in Spring JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have created a Postgres Gin index in a Spring Boot JPA application to allow fast text based search queries on a Text type column. Is it possible to define it using any native command that would execute on application deployment so I don't have to remember adding it to the table manually every time I deploy the microservice?
Using @Index in the @Table for the entity creates btree indexes.

This problem is also for a Hash type index I need. Btree is fine but Hash will be a bit faster for my queries so I'd like to automate those Gin & hash creation.

Comment: "*I don't have to remember adding it to the table manually*" - use a schema migration tool like Liquibase or Flyway. You should do DDL manually "on the fly" to begin with

Comment: Thanks but I need the Indexes to be created automatically when I deploy the microservice without having to take any manual actions.

Comment: You can integrate Liquibase into Spring Boot